# Access voilation reading location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, arm

I am trying to debugg the project on MSVS 2010.
Implementation  - c++; when i am degubbing the source code, i get the following failure reported by MSVS.

Failure reported:

```
"First chance exception at 0x00000013fb5b9ee in unit.exe: 0xc00000005 access voilation reading location 0x00000000000000c."
```

the problem lies in obtaining address.

```
int base = (*(abc::g_runc1.m_paulsenderpin.m_lastchunk_p)).xcpp::cxcppoutput::m_baseaddress;
```

my project is very big to include the source code,

In short it can be described as:
 - paul is a module with sender pin connected to c1.
 - xcpp is the interface

this source code and the project is correct and works without failure on ARM compiler, but on MSVS it gives access violation error.
On msdn there are some posts about permission set by assembly, and which avoids to read the addressed location. if so, how to change it... ?
or is there any better option to find the problem...?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `abc::g_runc1.m_paulsenderpin.m_lastchunk_p`? How is it declared? If it's a pointer, do you check that it's not `NULL`?

Comment: abc::g_runc1.m_paulsenderpin.m_lastchunk_p = 0x00000000000
paulsenderpin struct {pinbase,m_currentchunk,m_lastchunk,....}. memory is allocated to the paul for sender pin, memblock 1024 bytes.

additional to it, there are 8 such pins, paul, polly, raul, .....
baseaddress of all except paul are decleared the same way, and has no memory voialation error. only paul has this issue everywhere it is been used.

and MSVS throws exception for it, but the ARM does not.

Comment: If it's zero, then it means it's `NULL` and that's generally an illegal address.

Comment: Yes true...
but i cannot simple change the address or just randomly define it.
I understand its trying to access restricted area, and hence throws the error message.

Comment: Then *check* for `NULL` before accessing the pointer.

Comment: Use watch in debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem lies with the memory addressing, in ARM debugger 32 bits and MSVS10 48 bits of addressing, because of it the MSB byte is lost and so cannot find the correct memory address...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to access location that actually isn't owned by it's process. No data of user applications can be located at addresses so close to zero. As your expressions is too long to simply find where is the member containing zero reference, my tip is `m_last chunk_p`, and the `m_baseaddress` seems to be member at offset 12.

There is one simple explanation why does your code work fine when it's compiled by something that works with ARM: ARM uses aligned memory access, so class and structure members are aligned to full blocks, although they don't always use whole space allocated for them. Therefore you use bigger pointer or wrong `memset` parameters somewhere in your code and your pointer gets overwritten.

Problem may also disappear when you compile it with another version of (possibly another) compiler (or non machine with different processor architecture 32/64), as the size of fundamental types isn't always the same.

You should try to check what pointed is actually zero (or possibly 12) in your expression and try to set a watch on it. Be sure you use `sizeof` properly everywhere.

Comment: At the initialization, m_lastchunk = 0x00000000;
and does not change at all, which results in unhandled exception.
this error is at the very early stage, way before the actual working of the function, barely at the init.

Comment: So there isn't anything wrong, as you just forgot to set its value. You have two options left: you can initialize that member before it's being accessed, or you can use 'smart proxy' to allocate data only when it's accessed and not already allocated.

Comment: I tried initializing it, first of all it does not work out and the source code should be generic source code for ARM / MSVS. and i have constrain to change the source for the pins, c1 and xcpp, as i am using the structs and defines from these source codes, generated.

Does MSVS provides any alternative... ?
I know its dumb to ask, but due to constraints i have limited scope of modifications.

Comment: If aligned memory is suspected to cause this error, may be you can try to use *#pragma pack* as last resort? If the packsize is set equal to or greater than the default alignment, the packsize is ignored.
If the packsize is set smaller than the default alignment, the compiler aligns according to the packsize value.

Comment: This is not problem of language or environment, but of code architecture. You can go to project options->c\c++ and change alignment of structure members, but this won't solve the problem. I think that it doesn't run properly on ARM either. You must initialize that member. It is the only advice that can be given here.

Comment: @ user35443 - i mean, this way he could at least check if this is what hides the error in the code.

Comment: @SChepurin yes, that's true, although I think that wrong alignment would at least corrupt another values.

Comment: It does work perfectly without on ARM, because when is started i used the ARM Cortex Ax debugger. and not just here but in every further processing the baseadrres calculation works flawless. Now to integrate it with more forward i have to use MSVS.

About initialization, i did verify the init, 
m_lastchunk = m_currentchunk; and m_currentchunk receives the data from address passed over argument reserve (interf, baddress)

Comment: Program output can be perfect, and program may still contain something wrong. 
We can help you with syntax problems, compiler errors, exceptions or specific parts of code, but we can't help you with whole application. If you're not able to find the problem, you should comment-out critical sections and write them again. Good luck.

Comment: The Problem lies with the memory addressing, in ARM debugger 32 bits and MSVS10 48 bits of addressing, because of it the MSB byte is lost and so cannot find the correct memory address...!!!

Comment: Well, so is it problem? 
I have to ask on environment. I guess your MSVS runs on some Intel x86-64 machine that has 48-bits for memory addressing. Is it so?